# Swift, protocol conditional conformance, what's the difference between Element: Protocol and Element == Protocol when implement nested array?

Tags: swift

It's easier to describe it with a simple example,

```swift
protocol PlistNative { }

extension Bool   : PlistNative { }
extension String : PlistNative { }
extension Int    : PlistNative { }
```

Then, if we check the conditional conformance by type equality, i.e. treating the `PlistNative` protocol as a type,

```swift
extension Array: PlistNative where Array.Element == PlistNative { }

// success
let ary: [PlistNative] = [1, "hello", ["a", 6, ["hi"]]]
```

But, nested array wont' work if we treat it as a protocol, i.e. by checking if `Element` conforms to it,

```swift
extension Array: PlistNative where Array.Element: PlistNative { }

// Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected element type 'PlistNative'
let ary: [PlistNative] = [1, "hello", ["a", 6, ["hi"]]]
```

Why the type equality works, but the protocol conformance do not?

Comment: The difference is that when you say `Element: PlistNative` it means that the element type will conform to PlistNative. It needs to be a single element type therefore all elements in the array needs to be the same type (Bool, String or Int). The correct approach would be to create a generic method that the generic type conform to that protocol so that the resulting element would be of one of those types.

Comment: When you say  `Element == PlistNative` the element type is PlistNative, therefore any element that conform to PlistNative can be added to the array as its element. Note that this doesn't make any sense if the protocol doesn't have any property and or method requirement.

Comment: @LeoDabus I think your comments are very much the correct answer.